# Can Excel do basic time calculation on custom time format?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have log from a tool in this format: `hh:mm:ss.uuu`. 
For example: `10:12:34.323`

Setting these cells in Excel 2003 to time format with syntax `hh:mm:ss.000` is accepted, but any operation, like add/subtract, yelds to #Value! error.

Is there any way for Excel to do calculation on already set custom and recognized time format, without extra effort?

---

Update with screenshots:

[image: Format Cells]

[image: Evaluation]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd expect calculations like

`=A1+B1`

to work OK - even if your data  is text formatted - the addition should "co-erce" to a valid time value - perhaps you have extra characters in the data? What do you get with

`=LEN(A1)`

where A1 contains one of your time values - it should be 12

Comment: Are you saying it works for you fine? If that's so, can you tell me which Excel version are you running? I updated my question with screenshots. There are no extra chars in data

Comment: Yes, it works for me using Excel 2007 - if the data is numeric or text - Excel 2003 should be no different. It looks like your data is text - try using "text to columns" to convert - select column of times and just use Data > Text to columns > Finish - does that make any difference - do calcs work after that?

Comment: Well, you can see in formula bar and then in "Format Cell" sample box, from first screenshot that data is not text. Analogously your "Text to column" suggestion does not make difference.

Comment: Excel will let you set a number format to any cell, even if that cell contains text, so if I type "cat" into cell D1 I can still set the format of that cell to mm/dd/yy and the cell will still display "cat" - so just because the format of A1 is set to hh:mm:ss.000 that doesn't mean that the cell isn't text formatted - if you have a text formatted cell then you can't stop it being text by changing the number format - if you change the number format to general does that change how the data is displayed? If not then you have text - also test with ISNUMBER(A1)

Comment: As using "Text to column" with "general" format, doesn't change current state, do you maybe have any other suggestions?

Comment: Seems odd, because even if the data is text I would still expect =A2-A1 to work as I said in my answer - the obvious cause would be extra characters - if that isn't the case then the only other explanation I can think of is that some of the separator characters - ":" and "." are not the usual ones - is it possible to post a link to the workbook?

Comment: I uploaded UU encoded archive with workbook inside: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=S6zeqPqL It can be opened by WinRar or other tools. If that's a problem, please say it, I'll use some upload server in that case.

Comment: Yes - I can't access that in my current location - upload server would be good......

Comment: OK, here it is: https://hotfile.com/dl/191580717/70e5bbf/sample.xls.html

Comment: It works for me straight off! The data is text, when I use =ISNUMBER(A1) I get FALSE.....but =A2-A1 gives me 00:00:00.008 as expected. I don't think that Excel version makes a difference here - is it regional settings? If your regional settings expect a different decimal separator, e.g. commas instead of dots then it won't recognise the data as times.....

Comment: Thanks for your time. In the meantime I tried the same file on Excel 2007: http://i.imgur.com/MUIR21L.png It's a same error! Regional settings use expected `.` as decimal separator and `hh:mm:ss` as time format, and I confirmed the same in Excel Options.

Comment: I'm pretty much stumped - does it make any difference if you try `=TIMEVALUE(A2)-TIMEVALUE(A1)`

Comment: No changes in both 2003 and 2007: http://i.imgur.com/O6gZ0NI.png

Comment: OK trying to isolate the issue - do you get an error with this formula? `=RIGHT(A1,6)/86400`

Comment: No, I get valid value: 00:00:50.935

Comment: OK that looks right - that's what I get - how about the other part `=LEFT(A1,5)+0`

Comment: I get: 00.01.1900 10:31

Comment: It's odd that you get an error earlier but no errors on those - try this formula to get the difference between A1 and A2 `=LEFT(A2,5)+RIGHT(A2,6)/86400-LEFT(A1,5)-RIGHT(A1,6)/86400` - format result cell as hh:mm:ss.000

Comment: Thanks, that works fine. I asked this question, because I wanted to avoid extensive use of formulas next time I have to do calculation on similar data, but I guess there is some issue that won't let that happen. I'll leave question opened for one day, and if there are no other ideas why could this be happening, I'll mark your answer as correct. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: I'm not really sure why that works and the short formula doesn't - can you try `=A2-A1` again? The only character that isn't being used by the longer formula is the second colon

Comment: `=A2-A1` didn't magically correct itself unfortunately, it's same error.

Comment: Could you please use [chat] for extended discussion? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry - finished now I think.......

Answer (score 2):

You should check that the formats were actually applied to the cells.  In your screenshot you have double quotes around your values so they appear to just be strings.  If they were being properly interpreted I believe you would see something like 0.43836... for the dates instead of "10:31:16.465" in the formula evaluation window.